# Variance of coefficients in linear regression when responses are correlated

Tags: regression, variance, regression-coefficients

I have a linear regression problem given by:
$Y = X\beta+\epsilon$, where $Y\in R^n, X\in R^{n\times k}, \text{and }\beta \in R^k$. Rather than assuming that the error is independently distributed, i.e., uncorrelated, however, let us assume that $\epsilon \in N(0,\Sigma) $.

Where $\Sigma\in R^{n \times n}$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix with nonzero off-diagonal elements, which is unknown to us. In this case how can I estimate the variance of estimated coefficients $\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY?$

Comment: I would say "responses" rather than "response variables" in the title, I think ...

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question.